# Integrating sums of linearly independent functions yields nonnull integrals

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Let $f_1, \ldots,f_k$ be linearly independent functions from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and assume $\int f_j(x)dx>0$, for $j=1, \ldots,k$. Can we claim that
$$
\int \left| \sum_{j=1}^k c_jf_j(x) \right| dx>0
$$
for all vectors of linear coefficients $(c_1,\ldots,c_k)$ having at least one nonnull component?

**Remark:** clearly, assuming that the functions $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ are continuous, then  $\left| \sum_{j=1}^k c_jf_j \right|$ is a continuous function. It is also positive, in view of linear independence. Consequently $\int \left| \sum_{j=1}^k c_jf_j(x) \right|dx$ must be positive (recall that the integral of a nonnegative continuous function is null only if the function is null). Can we get to the same conclusion without assuming continuity?

Comment: Without continuity, you'd need to strengthen the hypothesis of linear independence in some way. For example, if $f_1$ is the characteristic function of $[0, 1],$ and $f_2$ is the characteristic function of $(0, 1],$ then $\int f_1 = \int f_2 = 1,$ and no non-trivial linear combination of $f_1$ and $f_2$ is zero everywhere, but $\int|f_1 - f_2| = 0.$ (By the way, the uses of the letters $k$ and $d$ in the question are mixed up somehow.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Calum Gilhooley I've also edited the question according to your remark.

Comment: If the number of functions, $k,$ must be the same as the dimension of the domain, then for $k=1,$ just take any function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is $0$ everywhere except at one point. As for the general question: if the integral is Lebesgue, and if the hypothesis of linear independence is strengthened to say that no non-trivial combination of the $f_j$ is zero almost everywhere, then the answer is trivially in the affirmative. Perhaps the hypothesis can be strengthened in some other way? (I'm giving this as a comment, not an answer, in case I'm confused, or the hypothesis is changed.)

Comment: Actually that example for $k=1$ doesn't work, because then $\int f_1 = 0.$ But one could modify my first example, to use the characteristic functions of $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ and $[0, 1] \times (0, 1],$ which seems to give a counterexample for $k=2.$